# Django How to Get rid of Migration Errors

Tags: django, migration, migrate, django-database, django-errors

I am using Django ; and when I change a model , getting an error **everytime** .

I am changing only one field in model, and getting stupidly a lot of errors **EVERYTIME**.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:

or

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:

or

> OperationalError no such column: table.colunm

or

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: "Table already exists"

and bla bla bla..

I got maybe all error types in Django , and now it is bothering me really.

I am trying all solutions everytime :

- Delete migrations
- find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "**init**.py" -delete
- find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
- Clear the migration history for each app
- Remove the actual migration files.
- Create the initial migrations
- Fake the initial migration
- python manage.py migrate --fake
- python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
- python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
- Drop database

Every solutions what i can find.

Stupidly trying all the solutions , and; at the last , yes i can find solutions BUT , I really really bored now from this stupidly errors.

Is there any way to get rid of migration errors in Django ?
Only I need the answer for this ; '**When I change a model field only, why am I getting these all madly errors, EVERYTIME ??!!!?**'

For example :

this is my model :

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from etahfiz.sabitler import DERS_SEVIYESI

# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
    systemId     = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True )
    adSoyad   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    dersSeviyesi = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=DERS_SEVIYESI )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.systemId)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    systemId = models.CharField(max_length=15 , unique=True)
    user   = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    adSoyad   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.systemId)

class StuTeach(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Talebe)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Hoca)
    tarihBas = models.DateField()
    tarihBit = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This was working perfectly , BUT ; I wanted to add only one field to **Teacher** Model :

```
dersSeviyesi = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=DERS_SEVIYESI )
```

Teacher model is like this now :

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    systemId = models.CharField(max_length=15 , unique=True)
    user   = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    adSoyad   = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    dersSeviyesi = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=DERS_SEVIYESI )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.systemId)
```

Aannd when I try to migrate :

```
python manage.py makemigrations sinif 
python manage.py migrate
```

> error error error
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: "Table already exists"

Or sth like that..

Everytime that change only one field, getting all errors of Django...

How can I get rid of this type errors ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your database and find migrations table and also delete on entries. Then run migrations again. At this time you may face ContentType already exists. THen delete content_type table. Or, the easiest solution is to delete the database and create again, but if you have important data, all data will be lost.